# Amplifier clipping output signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, troubleshooting, non-inverting

I constructed a noninverting amplifier with a sine wave input (0.5 Vpp) and observed an output signal that was clipped equally in both the positive and negative regions, to about 2.5 Vpp. I tried to narrow down the possible causes and made the following observations:

- The clipping occurs well below the level of the +/-15 V DC supplies (the values of which I verified using a multimeter)
- I'm using a signal frequency of 2 kHz, well below the region where I'd expect to see slew rate effects.
- I tried replacing Rf with a different resistor so that Rf=Ri, and the output looked as expected: a gain of 2 and a 1 Vpp sine wave output.

I'm trying to figure out if I'm making a silly mistake in my analysis, if one of my instruments is acting in a way I don't realize, or if I'm possibly working with a bad batch of op amps. I'd love any tips or things to try! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Without a schematic, any answer can only be based on complete wild guesses. (Of course it is likely that Spehro's guess is correct!)

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion is that you have your scope and probes set incorrectly (10:1) and you're actually seeing clipping at 25.7Vp-p, which would be about right for an LM741 operated from +/-15V.

This would occur if your probes are set to 10:1 but your 'scope is set to 1:1 so the voltages displayed are 10x higher than it appears. If you are using the oscilloscope to set input voltage then you would only notice it from the clipping.

For a "sanity check" use the oscilloscope to measure the DC voltage supplies.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Good suggestion on the probe attenuation factor--the only problem is that I checked the input signal using the same probe/channel and it showed up correctly on my scope. I also used the same probe when I tested with the matching resistor values and received the expected result. I'm using a digital oscilloscope (Keysight Infiniivision 2000 series), so I'm quite confident about the voltage measurements on those.

Comment: @Sparky47 See my edit. If you're checking both input and output with the same instrument you will only notice from the clipping since it's a linear circuit (before it clips).

Comment: Not that are very likely in my opinion unless your description is misleading. Op-amps clip when they get near the rails. If your output voltage with a gain of 2 is 10Vp-p that's well within the capability of a 741 on +/-15V.

Comment: Thanks Spehro! I understand now what you mean, and I agree this seems like the most likely cause. I'll check back in to let you know, and I appreciate your time!

Comment: @Sparky47 As Spehro mentions, also measure the power supply voltage with the scope since you have verified this with your DMM. My motto, never trust your test equipment unless you have verified it against a known.

Comment: Thanks qrk! Will do. This is really helpful advice.

Comment: Signal generators can also be set to the wrong output impedance and give you more than expected output voltage, but that's not what's happening here.